# Java version of MVVM?

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, mvvm

My partner and I decided to go with JSP, JAVA as our model for a social networking site.  At first, I was a bit afraid it would become a mess, but now it is still working fine and adding new features is not very hard.

However I still do have the bad feeling that we are going the wrong way. as far as I understand the main paradigam today is MVVM.  I was wondering

1. Does JAVA have any framework to support this?
2. is it worth migrating to SilverLight? ASP.NET?

Comment: Here is a link to an article which does three different patterns in a Java web application framework: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/zkjavaajax/ It is careful to use long names of the patterns not the M__ short hands which cause confusion as they mean different things to different people. The Presentation Model example is MVVM (aka MVB). The Supervising Controller is MVVMP (aka MVC). The Passive View example is MVP. It has full source code on github which has links to the code running on different cloud servers:  https://github.com/simbo1905/ZkToDo2

Answer (score 0):

Start asking these questions:

1. What is the most familiar to you and your team? (If you're all Java programmers, then find a good Java framework.)
2. What frameworks have a solid reputation for handling increasing complexity without becoming overly resistant to change? (Hint: Not PHP, at least not without a framework.)
3. What frameworks are proven scalable in production?
4. What frameworks are easiest to support in production?
5. What frameworks offer deployment flexibility (if that's a concern)?
6. How heavily will you use AJAX? Just a bit of PPR here and there or pure AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/), Microsoft Patterns and Practices Team guidance for developing web applications.

The back-end is MVC3 C# but you'll easily find a Java implementation for that.

Interesting is the front end.  It uses MVVM in JavaScript (Knockout.js)

Worthwile a visit!!

So I would say, go for a good Java MVC framework for the backend and use this guidance for the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can choose between Java, ASP.NET depending on the programmer's expertise you have. You also have a choice for Ruby and PHP too.

- For Java, I would suggest to go for a Seam Framework which encompasses JSF, Richfaces, Ajax and others . View [Seam Framework](http://seamframework.org).
- For ASP.NET you can go for MVC 3, even the site you are viewing is built on ASP.NET MVC 3. Visit [MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).
- For Ruby, you can go for Ruby on Rails which was one of the first to make an impact over the MVC framework way of development. View [Ruby on Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org).
- For PHP you can go for [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) for MVC framework.

---

**Specific Links for MVVM Framework:**

[Quick Tour of existing MVVM Frameworks](http://www.japf.fr/2009/10/a-quick-tour-of-existing-mvvm-frameworks/)

[MVVM light toolkit for WPF and Silverlight](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/06/14/mvvm-lsquolightrsquo-toolkit-for-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

[WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit&ProjectName=wpf)

[Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/)

[Silverlight.FX](http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX)

Comment: I would consider CakePHP and CodeIgniter MVC, not MVVM. Though from what I know they are two very similar patterns.

Comment: @Paul Yes CakePHP & CodeIgniter are MVC. MVVM is similar to MVC with very thin line of difference. The controller is replaced with a View Model. The View Model sits below the UI layer. The View Model exposes the data and command objects that the view needs. You could think of this as a container object that view goes to to get its data and actions from. The View Model pulls its data from the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about Java Web Ajax Programming, ZK Ajax framework supports MVVM design pattern seamlessly.

Following is some articles you might feel interested:

- [MVVM in ZK6 - Design your first MVVM page](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/November/MVVM_in_ZK_6_-_Design_your_first_MVVM_page)
- [MVVM in ZK6 - Design CRUD page by MVVM_pattern](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/November/MVVM_in_ZK_6_-_Design_CRUD_page_by_MVVM_pattern)

Its data binding system for MVVM design pattern utilizes EL 2.2 expression syntax, so it is quite flexible.

Comment: This ZK article covers  MVVM ("presentation model"), MVP ("passive view") and a hybrid MVVMP/MVC ("supervising controller")

Implementing event-driven GUI patterns using the ZK Java AJAX framework

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/zkjavaajax/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of this slides about Presentation Patterns. It is about which design pattern fit most to your application; not about which pattern is the best one.

http://www.slideshare.net/simbo1905/design-patterns-in-zk-java-mvvm-as-modelviewbinder

Comment: That presentation and it's sample code got written up and published as an article called "Implementing event-driven GUI patterns using the ZK Java AJAX framework" http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/zkjavaajax/